# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined !! React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have installed `react-router-dom` and I want to use `<Link>` from it.
Below is my code

```
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

    class UserList extends Component {

     renderList() {
        return this.props.users.map((user) => {
        return (
            <li
                key={user.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.selectUser(user)}
            >
                {user.first} {user.last}
            </li>
        );
    });
   }

   render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/admin/"> Click Me </Link>
        <ul>
            {this.renderList()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

   function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
       users: state.users
     };
   }

  function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({selectUser: selectUser}, dispatch);
   }


  export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

But getting this error

Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as   required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

any idea !!!

Comment: You can't use `Link` w/o providing `router` in context. So you need to wrap your root element with `BrowserRouter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have some root component called `App`.  You need to make its root node to be a router (say `BrowserRouter`) that will react on url changes and provide `Link` with correct router implementation via context.

```
// app.js
import { BrowserRouter, Route, } from 'react-router-dom'
import UserList from './path/to/UserListComponent'

class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        ...
        <Route path="/users" component={UserList}/>
        ...
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```